# Bar Chart Dc.Js Show percentage

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I have a bar charts with 3 categories in Dc.Js

I simply want to display the percentage of each row:

```
/ Construct the charts
              xdata = crossfilter(data);

              runDimension  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return "run-"+d.Run;})
              speedSumGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.Speed * d.Run;});


              var all = xdata.groupAll();
              dataCount.dimension(xdata)
                  .group(all);

              // Define the crossfilter dimensions
              cities = xdata.dimension(function (d) { return d.City; });
              locations = xdata.dimension(function (d) { return d.all; });
              var districttype = xdata.dimension(function (d) { return d.zip; });
              var wardTypes = xdata.dimension(function (d) { return d.ward; });
              var coordinates = xdata.dimension(function(d) { return d.geo; });
              var type = xdata.dimension(function(d) { return d.type; });

              // Marker Chart

              typeChart.width($('#type-chart').innerWidth()-30)
              .height(250)
              .colors(commonChartBarColor)
              .margins({top: 10, left: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20})
              .group(type.group())
              .dimension(type)
              .elasticX(true)
              .on("filtered", onFilt)
              .label(function (d) {
                  return d.data.key + "(" + Math.floor(d.data.value / all.value() * 100) + "%)";
                });
```

I've tried the label function but its not working.

Error: Unable to get property 'key' of undefined or null reference

How do i do that?

Solution:

```
typeChart.width($('#type-chart').innerWidth()-30)
          .height(250)
          .colors(commonChartBarColor)
          .margins({top: 10, left: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20})
          .group(type.group())
          .dimension(type)
          .elasticX(true)
          .ordering(function(d) {
             return -d.value
          })
          .label(function (d) {
              if (typeChart.hasFilter() && !typeChart.hasFilter(d.key))
                  return d.key + " (0%)";
              var label = d.key;
              if(all.value())
                  label += " (" + Math.floor(d.value / all.value() * 100) + "%)";
              return label;
          })
          .xAxis().ticks(5);
```

Comment: Have you looked at what data you are receiving in `d`? At a quick glance your approach looks correct but there are [some nasty inconsistencies between the different charts in the ways accessors are called](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/703). This kind of error generally means that the format is not what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Ive found solution, Ive put it in the code!

Comment: Great, thanks for following up!